# Angular js:How to append the data into the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

Hi I am implementing a website in angularjs.

I am facing a problem. I have a widget which shows 10 records at a time, when i click on view more button it fetches next 10 records based on page number.

I have implemented a button

```
`<button ng-click="loadYourRecs(true)">click here for Recs</button>
```

Now on click of the button I am calling the controller and getting the data like so:-

```
 $scope.loadRated = function(flag){

        if(flag==true)
        {
            $rootScope.TopPge +=1;
        }
        // call api
        var $ratedSpinner = $('.rated-spin');
        loading('show',{element: $ratedSpinner});
        userAPI.topRated({userid: $rootScope.getUser().userid, pageno:$rootScope.TopPge}, function(r){

            var loading = $filter('loading');
            loading('hide', { element: $('#loadIndicator2') });

            $scope.ratedLoaded = true;

            loading('hide',{element: $ratedSpinner});
            $scope.programs.rated = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist;

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-398742-8']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','WOITopRated','TopRated','Load']);

            for(i=0; i<$scope.programs.rated.length; i++){
                //abbreviates the month
                $scope.programs.rated[i].timestring = abbrMonth($scope.programs.rated[i].timestring) ;
            }
            // called with timeout for dom creation
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(openTabIndex === 3) {
                    showTab(openTabIndex);
                }
                showMoreOnTab(3);
            }, 5);
        });
    };
```

`
I am getting the data via api call.

Th Html code is as follows:-

```
<div class='channel-tabs hidden-phone' ng-controller='Home_ProgramsTabController' ng-init='init()'>
<div class='tab clearfix' ng-show="currentActiveTab == 'rated'">

          <div class='item' ng-repeat='p in programs.rated' home-tab-item watchable="p" ></div>

        <div id="space-for-buttons">
          <div class = 'rated-spin' ng-show = 'programs.rated == 0 && ratedLoaded == false'> </div>
          <div ng-show="programs.rated == 0  && ratedLoaded == true" class="noResultsBlock">No Results for Rated.</div>
          <div class='clearfix'></div>
        </div>

          <div ng-controller="Home_ProgramsTabController" ng-app="woi">

            <button ng-click="loadRated(true)">click here for Rated</button>

          </div>

        </div>
```

Now the problem I am facing is The data which is fetched replaces the older content in the target div. I want to append it.

Comment: Could you include the HTML code?
In any case, if you want to append data, you shouldn¡t be reasigning values with this line:  $scope.programs.rated = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist;
You should just loop over the returned data and append them to the existing array

Comment: include your html code

Comment: Offtopic. Wow, I wonder how come you having such a well structured framework like angular ended up with a spaghetti code like this.

Comment: @Eylen Please check the code

Comment: @Athi..i have included the html code.please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userAPI.topRated({userid: $rootScope.getUser().userid, pageno:$rootScope.TopPge}, function(r){

        var loading = $filter('loading');
        loading('hide', { element: $('#loadIndicator2') });

        $scope.ratedLoaded = true;

        loading('hide',{element: $ratedSpinner});

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-398742-8']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','WOITopRated','TopRated','Load']);

        for(i=0; i<r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist; i++){
            //abbreviates the month
            var el = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist[i];
            el.timestring = abbrMonth(el.timestring) ;
           $scope.programs.rated.push(el);
        }
        // called with timeout for dom creation
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(openTabIndex === 3) {
                showTab(openTabIndex);
            }
            showMoreOnTab(3);
        }, 5);
    });
```

Comment: @Eylen..Thanks a lot for the help.It worked and helped me a lot.The only change I had to make was to make $scope.programs.rated into $rootScope.programs.rated

Answer (score 1):

You need to append data to array.

```
        loading('hide',{element: $ratedSpinner});
        var newRated = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist;

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-398742-8']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','WOITopRated','TopRated','Load']);

        for(i=0; i<newRated.length; i++){
            //abbreviates the month
            newRated[i].timestring = abbrMonth(newRated.timestring) ;
        }

        //append
        $scope.programs.rated = ($scope.programs.rated||[]).concat(newRated);
```

Or

```
$scope.programs.rated.push.apply($scope.programs.rated, newRated);
```